# Facing a issue when trying to use a IF statement with arrays

Tags: javascript

I am creating a shopping cart for a uni project, but facing problems when testing my array. If more than 5 elements are selected the total price should have a 10% discount. The variable discount works fine when just one element is selected for a quantity bigger than 5 but returns 0 if the quantity is split between two elements (meaning if POTATOS = 6 the discount works BUT IF POTATOS = 4 and BLUEBERRY = 2 it doesnt work anymore ). 
Here the code :

```
    function Calc() {
        var numberPotatos = document.getElementById('potatos_id').value;
        var numberBlueberry =  document.getElementById('blueberry_id').value;
        var numberStrawberry = document.getElementById('strawberry_id').value;
        var numberEggplants = document.getElementById('eggplants_id').value;
        var numberKiwis = document.getElementById('kiwis_id').value;
        var numberBananas = document.getElementById('bananas_id').value;

        var output = "";



        var MyArray= new Array (6); 
            MyArray [0] = numberPotatos;
            MyArray [1] = numberBlueberry;
            MyArray [2] = numberStrawberry;
            MyArray [3] = numberEggplants;
                MyArray [4] = numberKiwis;
            MyArray [5] = numberBananas;

         var MySecondArray  = new Array (6);
MySecondArray [0] = 6;
MySecondArray [1] = 7;
MySecondArray [2] = 5;
MySecondArray [3] = 22;
MySecondArray [4] = 12;
MySecondArray [5] = 4;

// MORE CODE 


var sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i< MyArray.length; i++) {
    sum += MyArray [i ]* MySecondArray[i];
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = sum;
}

    var discount = 0;  
    for(var i=0; i<MyArray.length;i++ )
     { 
        if(MyArray[i] > 5){  
           discount = (sum - (sum * 0.10));
            discount = parseFloat(discount);
      }
      document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = discount;
      }



}
```

Comment: Read your own question. Do you seriously expect anyone to know what your problem is?

Comment: @Marcin It makes perfect sense to me. Fiddling with the JS as we speak.

Comment: @DannyBeckett "It doesn't work". Obviously this makes sense, because software only has one mode of failure.

Comment: It stops working when the total for any one item is less than 6 because you only check for single items being greater than 6. Just take a sum of everything in `MyArray` and check if that is greater than 6.

Comment: Did you try using one of those things called a "debugger"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of the total items, rather than if one item is more than 5:

```
var totalItems = 0;
var discount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < MyArray.length; i++)
{
    totalItems += MyArray[i];
}

if(totalItems > 5){
    discount = (sum - (sum * 0.10));
    discount = parseFloat(discount);
}
```

Comment: Why did you copy that `discount = parseFloat(discount);` part?

Comment: @Bergi It's just the OP's original code to calculate the discount... I just added `var totalItems = 0;`, `totalItems += MyArray[i];` and moved the rest of the logic outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: If you intend to give good answers you should correct all mistakes, not only those that were asked for :-)

Comment: works fine!! sorry for my grammar, but English is not my first language

Comment: sorry to bother you Danny, I am still in trouble with this code. Any chance you have an e-mail address where I can contact you?

Comment: @greatTeacherOnizuka Is it closely related to this problem? If so, edit your question to include what's wrong now. Otherwise, it'd be better if you could ask a new question and post the link here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your checking just for more than 5 pieces of each given article:

`if(MyArray[i] > 5){`

Not for the total articles, you should sum all the pieces your getting for all different articles, so I suggest you do it like this instead:

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i< MyArray.length; i++) {
    sum += MyArray [i ]* MySecondArray[i];
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = sum;
var discount = 0;
var totalQuantity = 0;
for(var i=0; i<MyArray.length;i++ ){ 
    totalQuantity += MyArray[i];
}
if(totalQuantity > 5){  
    discount = sum*0.9;
}
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = discount;
```

Comment: Please move the first sum assignment outside of the loop